# Generating ws client using WSDL in java6

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am first time working with wsdl. I apologize if its a very novice question.

I have a wsdl file for a webservice. I want to create a java console application to consume the service.
I have generated class files using wsimport tool and wsdl. A good number of class file have generated. 
I am confused at this point should I need further documentation from webservice provider to implement the service or there is any conversion regarding using the generated files.
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3745701/Enterprise-Java-Contract-First-vs-Contract-Last-Web-Services.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL file already have whole definition you need, including data-type, request and response wrappers for every method, etc. That mean, that since you have generated the client implementation via wsimport, the only thing you have to do is to import this files into your current java project and use it to access the web-service.

You can find a wide number of examples, how to use this generated client code. Here is [one of them](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/). In short, you have two main generated classes, representing web-service: an Interface annotated with `@WebService` annotation and some service annotated with `@WebServiceClient`. You just need to get an instance of the intarface from the service, like:

```
HelloWorldImplService helloService = new HelloWorldImplService();
HelloWorld hello = helloService.getHelloWorldImplPort();
```

Here us `HelloWorld` is an interface, which provides all the methods of the web-service from WSDL. And then you'll get it, you can use it to call the web-service. Just don't forget, that you may have to override the default ip-address of the web-service client, if it's not the one you need.

The only additional documentation you may need, is some documentations providing the information about the web-service business purposes, which may be usefull for the developer, whot interacts with this web-service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can create a service client object from the class annotated with `@WebServiceClient` and call the related method with parameters.

```
WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
AnswerType answer = client.GetSoap().theMethodYouWantUse(some_parameters);
```